# How to concatenate filename and extension string?

Tags: php, filenames

I want to create filename strings with ".xml" extension.

I have `$fileName` variable, but I don't know how to combine the variable with ".xml" extension.

For example: From the file names book1, book2, catalog1, catalog2, I want the following output: book1.xml, book2.xml, catalog1.xml, catalog2.xml.

Comment: `"file_name".$var.".xml"` ?

Comment: Is this a real question?

Comment: this code works for me, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the filename stored within the `$fileName` variable, you can use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) to join the two strings together.

For example:

```
$fileName = "catalog1";
$extension = "xml";

// You can use the double quotes to build strings like this:
$fileNameWithExtension = "$fileName.$extension";

// Or you can concatenate using the "." operator:
$fileNameWithExtension = $fileName . "." . $extension;

// Of course, there are many ways to skin a cat:
$fileNameWithExtension = implode(".", [$fileName, $extension]);
$fileNameWithExtension = sprintf("%s.%s", $fileName, $extension);
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can concatenate strings using the `.`

So if the file name is in a variable called `$filename` then do

```
$filename = 'a_file_name';
$filename_extn = $filename . '.xml';
```

Or to add the extension to the existing variable you can use the `.=` concatenator like so

```
$filename = 'a_file_name';
$filename .= '.xml';
```